# Hive installation issue while following Hive apache wiki step by step

Tags: hadoop, hive

After installed Hive by the instruction on Hive apache wiki step by step, I invoked hive shell and typed "CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);", then it comes following error, log is also included.

I'm new to Hive, any suggestion or comments? Thanks a lot! I found the questions asked over google the web, but did not find solution.

I use single machine mode for Hadoop on Mac.

hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

log file:

```
Last login: Tue Jun 14 00:27:51 on ttys001
Zhiyong-Xies-MacBook-Pro:~ hadoop$ cat /tmp/*/hive.log
2011-06-14 00:31:54,834 ERROR metastore.HiveMetaStore (HiveMetaStore.java:executeWithRetry(334)) - JDO datastore error. Retrying metastore command after 1000 ms (attempt 1 of 1)
2011-06-14 00:31:56,012 ERROR exec.DDLTask (SessionState.java:printError(374)) - FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:491)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3233)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:221)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:132)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1238)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1050)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:885)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:224)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:358)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:593)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1186)
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:237)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:266)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:199)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:174)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:369)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.executeWithRetry(HiveMetaStore.java:321)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:466)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:240)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.(HiveMetaStore.java:203)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:107)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2010)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2020)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:485)
     ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
     at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
     ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:443)
     at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:355)
     at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:215)
     at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:156)
     at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.registerExtensionPoints(PluginManager.java:82)
     at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.(OMFContext.java:156)
     at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.(OMFContext.java:137)
     at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseOMFContext(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:132)
     at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseProperties(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:363)
     at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:307)
     at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:255)
     at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:182)
     ... 40 more

2011-06-14 00:31:56,014 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(374)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Answer (score 1):

http://getsatisfaction.com/cloudera/topics/hive_error_error_in_metadata_javax_jdo_jdofatalinternalexception

Removing the $HADOOP_HOME/build directory worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the directory $HADOOP_HOME/build (actually just renaming it) also works for hive-0.9.0 and hadoop-1.0.4.